# Expose Strapi Prometheus Metrics on another Port

Tags: strapi

I’m using [strapi v4](https://strapi.io/) along with the [prometheus plugin](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-prometheus) and right now my app metrics are being exposed on `http://localhost:1337/api/metrics`
But I need it to be on another port like `http://localhost:9090/metrics` (also removing the `api` prefix).

So strapi and the rest of the backend would still be running on port `1337` and only the metrics on `9090`

I've been through the documentation but it seems like there is no configuration for that. Can anybody help think of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the metrics don't run on a separate server. They run on the same server as strapi.

This is to be able to use the user-permissions plugin and the API token of strapi to secure the endpoint.

In the future, I could look into making it an option to create a separate server.